# Can angular checkbox post a boolean with ng-model, not a string?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

The following code will give `support_enable='true'` when checked, and null if it's unchecked.

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="support_enable" ng-value="config.support_enable" ng-model="config.support_enable">
</form>
```

The following code will give `support_enabled='on'` when checked, or null if unchecked.

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="support_enable" ng-model="config.support_enable">
</form>
```

I want to know is there a way to post a boolean value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call a function on `ng-change` and update variable value boolean according to the getting value

```js
// in your controller

$scope.checkValue = function(value){
  if(value == 'on'){
    config.support_enable = true;
  }
  else 
    config.support_enable = false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="support_enable" ng-model="config.support_enable" ng-change="checkValue(config.support_enable)">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it in old way, before checkbox insert hidden field

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="support_enable" ng-value="config.support_enable" ng-model="config.support_enable">
<input type="checkbox" name="support_enable" ng-model="config.support_enable">
</form>
```

Comment: form always send last element, so if checkbox checked - it's checkbox, if not - it's hidden field.

Comment: I want to post a boolean value, the post is just a string.

Comment: config.support_enable - put boolean here

Comment: it will post a 'on' string